# Adjust token information during process runtime

Tags: winapi, process

I'm creating a process with `TokenUIAccess` enabled (using `SetTokenInformation` before creating the process). After the process is running I would like to disable/enable the `TokenUIAccess` for the process (without restarting the process).

Is there a way to adjust the token information during process runtime? I'm expecting to find something like `AdjustTokenInformation` (similar to `AdjustTokenPrivileges`) but such doesn't exist.

Comment: in what problem - again call `SetTokenInformation` for process token

Comment: but then I need to somehow set again the modified token on the process, which is what I'm looking for

Comment: in sense ? simply open process token and call `SetTokenInformation` for this token. all. `OpenProcess` token give you direct access to process token. not to it copy. all modification which you do with this token direct affect process. you not need "set modified token"

Comment: If the problem is that you need to do this within the process itself, you won't be able to enable `TokenUIAccess` again without SeTcbPrivilege. Try disabling it for the current thread token while impersonating self. Then you can revert to self to effectively enable it again.

Comment: for set `TokenUIAccess` to true we really need `SeTcbPrivilege`. for set it to false we not need any privileges.

Comment: I called again `SetTokenInformation` - the function succeeds but it doesn't actually affect the process.